# Binding two different Properties to one TextBlock based on boolean value in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have following problem: I have `UserControl` which `DataContext` is set to one object with two different Properties (beside others): `Price (decimal)` and `AlternativePrice (string)`.

In `UserControl` I have `TextBlock` which `Text` Property I want to set based on evaluating `AlternativePrice == decimal.Zero`.

If it's `true`, `Text` Property should be set to `Text={Binding Price}`, if `false`, then `Text={Binding AlternativePrice}`.

I found some guides that mention `Triggers` using, but I wasn't able to make it run.
Is there a way how to do something like this?

Here is part of my code:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="..." x:Name="priceTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ?}"/>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't use WPF, but I would suspect in your processing code (.cs code behind) you need to check against your field that you want to be data bound (IE: IF(AlternativePrice.equals(decimal.zero)) {priceTextBlock.BindingSource={Binding Price} else {priceTextBlock.BindingSource={Binding AlternativePrice}

Comment: I just realized how stupid I am and how easily it can be done in code behind with things you wrote :-P My fault. Thanks for idea anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a converter:

```
class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    decimal v1 = (decimal)values[0];
    decimal v2 = (decimal)values[1];

    decimal res = v1 != 0 ? v1 : v2;
    return res.ToString();
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string[] splitValues = ((string)value).Split(' ');
    return splitValues;
  }
}
```

Usage in XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <converter:MyConverter x:Key="Conv" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Conv}">
      <Binding Path="AlternativePrice" />
      <Binding Path="Price" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Of course you should add some checking in the `Convert` method (`values != null`, `values.Count == 2` and so on).

Comment: Thanks for alternative, I'll save this for future use.